# Cannot create Price Set in Wordpress

Tags: price-sets

I'm using CiviCRM in Wordpress but I got an issue when creating a Price Set. If I click to Save a new Price Set https://prnt.sc/1trrm1u, it auto redirect to the page that shows all price set, it should be showing a popup to add a new price field https://prnt.sc/1trs53n.

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this issue? please help me.
Thanks so much!

Comment: always worth seeing if you can replicate on the master site ie https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and had no problems creating one https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fprice&reset=1

Comment: maybe you can try using the paths from that example to see if you can visit the page directly

Comment: Thanks, @petednz-fuzion,  I follow you guide, the demo link worked correct, but it not work on my site

Comment: Did you "try using the paths from that example to see if you can visit the page directly" on your site

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, Thanks, I fixed this issue by the way update CiviCRM plugin.

Comment: Thanks for letting everyone know. would you pls Accept the answer below so this does not stay open

Answer (score 1):

If the issue cannot be replicated on the demo or master sites eg https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ then it suggests that either

- a problem has been fixed and it is worth upgrading to see if this resolves it
- there is something specific about your installation, configuration or environment.